# updates into inserts

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Need to insert update statements into a table .

col4 value of table1 is used by table2 to update the column of table3.

how to write insert statements to insert the value as update statement. Please help.

Table1

[image: col1,col2 1]

table 2
[image]

---

### EDIT

`col1` from `X_DATA` table I am fetching into `L_col1` variable using cursor and I want to insert the
data into the table `INSERT_UPDATES` (only one column with update statement) as below

> update main_table set column1=L_col1

```sql
Declare
  CURSOR GET_DATA select col1 from X_DATA where process_status='P';
BEGIN
  OPEN GET GET_DATA;
  FETCH GET_DATA INTO L_col1;
  INSERT INTO INSERT_UPDATES values( "update main_table set column1=L_col1" not sure how to fetch data here );
  CLOSE GET_DATA;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
END GEN_DATA;
END;
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73)

Comment: Can you please help with the query

Comment: What do you mean by "used by table 2"? Is there a trigger involved somehow? Please provide a more complete description of your requirements, sample data in all three tables, and if possible any code that you've already attempted.

Comment: Hi 
col1 from X_DATA table I am  fetching into L_col1  variable using cursor and I want to insert the data into the table INSERT_UPDATES (only one column with update statement) as below 
"update main_table set column1=L_col1" 

Declare
CURSOR GET_DATA
 select col1 from  X_DATA  where process_status='P'; 
  BEGIN
 OPEN GET GET_DATA;
 FETCH GET_DATA INTO L_col1 ;
INSERT INTO INSERT_UPDATES values( "update main_table set column1=L_col1" not sure how to fetch data here );
CLOSE GET_DATA;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE;
    END GEN_DATA;
END;

Comment: Please help with the query